# Why two Node.js Buffers are equal when the allocated strings are different?

Tags: node.js, jwt, buffer, jose

Kindly ask you to help with the following.
I'm trying to understand how the JOSE library works for JWE creating/validation in Node.js.

To create a JWE I need a secret key in KeyObject or Uint8Array format.
I have a secret string in my .env file and want to create a secret key based on that.

```
const secret = Buffer.alloc(32, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
const jwe = await new jose.EncryptJWT({ userId: '1234532' })
.setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'dir', enc: 'A256GCM' })
.setIssuedAt()
.setIssuer('urn:example:issuer')
.setAudience('urn:example:audience')
.setExpirationTime('2h')
.encrypt(secret);
```

Works fine, we created a JWE.

Then I want to provide an invalid secret, changing my .env key.

```
const secretWithInvalidString = Buffer.alloc(32, process.env.INVALID_SECRET);
const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtDecrypt(jwt, secretWithInvalidString, {
  issuer: 'urn:example:issuer',
  audience: 'urn:example:audience'
});
```

My JWE is still VALID but it shouldn't be as I changed a secret string in .env file.

After comparing two buffers with different strings I can see that they are equal, but why?

```
// returns true but why when provided strings to Buffer are different?
   console.log(console.log(secret.equals(secretWithInvalidString)));
```

P.S. I haven't worked with Buffers too much before :|

THANKS!

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help you to solve the problem, but I noticed that you're passing a variable called secret1 to the encrypt method, shouldn't you pass the secret variable?

Comment: Edited, but it's not the case here :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're passing a string longer than 32 octets in either both cases or at least one of them and the different octets are at the end.

[Buffer.alloc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferallocsize-fill-encoding), the way you call it, allocates 32 bytes and fills it with whatever you pass but will not exceed the 32 bytes allocated.

You probably want to use [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding) instead.